# Is it possible to find the parent frame of a joint knowing the joint name?

Tags: ros, joint, frame, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am using the ros control JointStateController to publish the JointStates from gazebo. I get the messages and it is working well. Now that I have the joint state I would also like to find the transform from map frame to the joint location (parent frame of the joint). If I know the name of the parent frame of this joint I can always do it with tf. But since the we are using this code with different robot models, the parent frame of the joint is not always the same. But I do have the joint name from the JointState message and this joint will always have a parent in the robot description.

Is it possible to somehow lookup the parent frame of a joint using the joint name?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375071/is-it-possible-to-find-the-parent-frame-of-a-joint-knowing-the-joint-name?/) by [dregel](https://answers.ros.org/users/71922/dregel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ended up reading it from the urdf robot model (usually /robot_description in parameter server). You can use model::getJoint with the joint name and get the parent_link_name attribute from the return value.

---

Originally posted by [dregel](https://answers.ros.org/users/71922/dregel/) with karma: 16 on 2021-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0